# I am getting back NaN / inaccurate year numbers when converting epoch date to human readable date in javascript. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, epoch

The parseDate function below results in odd date outputs, especially when using .getFullYear(). Why is this happening and how do I correct the code below?

```
const parseDate = (epochDate) => {
        var date = new Date(epochDate * 1000);
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var fullDate = day + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year;
        console.log("date", epochDate)
    }
parseDate(412992000000) //output: 12-3-15057
parseDate(-232848000000) //output: 4-5--5409
```

Comment: Remove the ``*1000``

Comment: OR remove the last 3 0s from the input ;)

Comment: removing the last 3 0s worked - thank you!

Comment: It was a joke. Un*x has dates in seconds since era, JS has it in milliseconds